# AutoCompleteTextView: provide values in XML?

Tags: android, material-design, autocompletetextview, mdc-components

Is it possible to provide values to the `AutoCompleteTextView` in XML / via resources, therefore without setting an adapter in code?

I want to use the `AutoCompleteTextView` as part of an [exposed dropdown menu](https://material.io/components/menus/#exposed-dropdown-menu), so all values shall be shown at once and no filtering shall happen. Also all values to be shown are known at compile time.

Answer (score 2):

I think you can do that by using the list via Resource and implementing it in AutoCompleteTextView passing by the adapter.

See the example here :

```
public class CountriesActivity extends Activity {
     protected void onCreate(Bundle icicle) {
         super.onCreate(icicle);
         setContentView(R.layout.countries);

         ArrayAdapter<String> adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this,
                 android.R.layout.simple_dropdown_item_1line, COUNTRIES);
         AutoCompleteTextView textView = (AutoCompleteTextView)
                 findViewById(R.id.countries_list);
         textView.setAdapter(adapter);
     }

     Resources res = getResources();
     private static final String[] COUNTRIES = res.getStringArray(R.array.planets_array);
 }
```

Hope this could help you or any one else .

Answer (score -1):

Yes its possible. There is a method `showDropDown()` which you can call.

Try something like

```
autoCompleteTextView.showDropDown()
```

Reference :
https://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/AutoCompleteTextView.html#showDropDown()